# Using gulp.src() to include all files EXCEPT js files NOT in 3rd party dir

Tags: gulp

I am trying to copy all files EXCEPT js files that are not in the directory `3rd`.

This is what I was doing:

```
return gulp.src([
        'src/**/*',
        '!src/**/*.js', // no js files from src
        'src/**/3rd/*.js' // make sure to get 3rd party js files though
    ])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

However this would not copy ANY js files :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In gulp 3.x globs passed to `gulp.src()` are not evaluated in order. That means it is not possible to exclude a set of files and then reinclude a subset of the excluded files.

This will be possible with the [upcoming gulp 4.0](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/4.0/CHANGELOG.md#400):

> globs passed to gulp.src will be evaluated in order, which means this is possible `gulp.src(['*.js', '!b*.js', 'bad.js']`) (exclude every JS file that starts with a `b` except `bad.js`)

For gulp 3.x there is the [`gulp-src-ordered-globs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-src-ordered-globs) package which can be used in place of the regular `gulp.src()`:

```
var gulpSrc = require('gulp-src-ordered-globs');

return gulpSrc([
    'src/**/*',
    '!src/**/*.js', // no js files from src
    'src/**/3rd/*.js' // make sure to get 3rd party js files though
  ])
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

Comment: Thanks Sven for this!