# Modify path of gulp.dest

Tags: gulp

My goal is to find the binaries in here, and elevate them to the first subdir in `exe` dir.

My simplified (in reality it has more junk, more subdirs)  folder structure is this:

```
src
├── exe
│   └── nix
│       └── binary.out
│       └── blah
│   └── mac
│       └── binary.out
│       └── blah
│   └── win
│       └── src
│           └── trigger
│                └── trigger
│                    └── trigger
│                        └── binary.exe
│                    └── Debug
```

My goal is to copy just the binary files into `dist/exe` like this:

```
dist
├── exe
│   └── nix
│       └── binary.out
│   └── mac
│       └── binary.out
│   └── win
│       └── binary.exe
```

This is the code I use right now:

```
var path = require('path');

gulp.src(['src/exe/**/*.out', 'src/exe/**/*.exe'])
  .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file) {
    var os = file.path.match(/(?:win|mac|nix)/)[0];
    return 'dist/exe/' + os + '/' + path.basename(file.path);
  }));
```

However this is still copying the structure even after the os name. It's like it appends the `**/` stuff after my returned string. Is there any way to make it not do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It like appends the **/ stuff after my returned string. Is there anyway to make it not do this

Yep, that's exactly what it does and it's intentional. Anything before the `**` is treated as the base path, anything after is the path that is used when writing the file to the destination directory. (See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35845039/how-base-option-affects-gulp-src-gulp-dest) if you want to know more).

Normally you could use the [`base` option](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/v3.9.1/docs/API.md#optionsbase) in `gulp.src()` to change this, but this doesn't really work in your case since you would need one base path for `nix`/`mac` and another one for `win`.

On top of all that you're using `gulp.dest()` wrong. `gulp.dest()` specifies the destination **directory**. You're trying to use it to specify a destination **file**. That's not possible.

The easiest solution for you is to use [`gulp-rename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rename):

```
var path = require('path');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.src(['src/exe/**/binary.{exe,out}'])
  .pipe(rename(function(file) {
    file.dirname = file.dirname.split(path.sep)[0];
  }))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/exe'));
```

Comment: Thank you Sven for such a great answer! I really learned a lot from it and got a solution! gulp-rename does the trick! Very interesting thing I learned also is that `{exe,out}`, thanks!

Comment: By chance can gulp-rename discard directories? Right now I am getting the binary in the 1st subdir, but i am also getting empty folders next to it.

Comment: No, it can't completely discard directories, only change their path. But you shouldn't end up with empty dirs anyway, at least not if your `gulp.src()` only selects the `binary` files.

Comment: Ah crap. I needed to select binary files that had no `.` in it. So I did this: `var gulp_src_ordered = require('gulp-src-ordered-globs'); gulp_src_ordered(['../' + addonname + 'Exe/**/*', '!../' + addonname + 'Exe/**/*.*', '../' + addonname + 'Exe/**/*.exe' ])` - i am selecting ALL, then remove things that HAVE a `.` in it. Is there any other way to get all exe files and files that have no `.` in it? Excuse the XY question please.

Comment: I don't really get it. A file like `binary.exe` does have a `.` in it, so should it be included or excluded? Honestly this is better asked as new question with a directory listing that shows which files you want to include/exclude.

Comment: Thanks Sven! I'll do some troubleshooting and post a question if I ca't figure it out. The gulp_src_ordered works like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205232/using-gulp-src-to-include-all-files-except-js-files-not-in-3rd-party-dir - it includes all files, then it excludes any that have a `.` in it, then it in includes all files with a `.exe` ending.